# Translate city names and country

Tags: mysql, database

I Have mysql db with country e cities of the world; it are in english but my site is multilanguage (italian, french, russian ecc) - how can I do to translate the various locality?

Answer (score 4):

You could use http://www.geonames.org. There all cities in the world, with translations.

**UPDATED**:
You could use geonames web service, for example [translation of Moscow](http://api.geonames.org/search?name=moskva&country=RU&featureCode=PPLC&maxRows=10&type=rdf&username=demo). Of course you are to parse this XML data :)

Comment: I know geonames, I did the dump in mysql but is very complicated.

I have these tables:
admin1Codes
Struttura admin1CodesAscii
Struttura alternatename
Struttura continentCodes
Struttura countryinfo
Struttura featureCodes
Struttura geoname
Struttura iso_languagecodes
Struttura timeZones

how do I translate the name of a place?